# How to lock a cell value after taking 1st instance value from different cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, date

```
End Date       Original End Date                
4/13/2017      4/13/2017------------>  1st instance value
```

If the user changes date in `End Date` Column, the date in `Original End Date` column should not get changed (It should take first value entry from End Date). `Original End Date` column should be freezed to 1st entry date in `End Date` Column.

If user changes End date, it should be like this:

```
End Date    Original End Date               
4/20/2017   4/13/2017------------> End Date is changed.
```

But the Original End date remains same as 1st End date.

Is there any Excel formula or VBA code for this?

Also, the sheet should not be protected to meet this requirement.

Comment: What column is `End Date` ? and what column is `Original End Date` ?

Comment: End Date is in P column, Original End Date is in Q Column

Comment: Try the answer and code below

Comment: Please describe more clearly the situation. Where does the End Date and the Original End Data column get its value from (User input, Excel formula, VBA code, Linked to and external data source, etc.)? Post your code (if you have any) and attach screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column A is End Date and column B is Original End Date, place the below code on Sheet Module. To do so, right click on the Sheet Tab --> View code and paste the code given below into the opened code window --> Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If Target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then Target.Offset(0, 1) = CDate(Target)
ElseIf Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If Target <> "" Then Application.Undo
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code will only allow the user to input the End Date in Column A only. And the first instance will be recorded in corresponding cell in column B. Later user can neither change the date in column B nor enter any date or content in column B. i.e. column B will be locked for any user input and it will only accept the date entered first time in column A.

Comment: Yes this is the one I'm looking for.. The original date should be non editable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `End Date` is in column "P", and `Original End Date` is in column "Q".

So place the code below, in your relevant worksheet's code, the code will work only if a value in Column "P" is modified.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 16 Then ' check if the value modified is in Column "P"
    If Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "" Then '<-- check if the value in Column "Q" is empty
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Target.Value ' modify value of Column "Q" to value of Column "P"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The original date is editable. It should be un editable.

Comment: @SunnyJayadev this is not what you requested in your post

Comment: @SunnyJayadev it's ok, as long as you got the answer you were looking for